# How to get props of rendered component

Tags: react-native-testing-library

Imagine, I have a react native component:

```
const HelloWorld = (props) => (
<View>
<Text>Hello World</Text>
</View>)
```

I want to run a test to refer to HelloWorld component itself and check for a prop. How do I access HelloWorld itself and retrieve its props?

I didn't find options like baseElement as used in other similar libraries

Answer (score 1):

```
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
...

  let rendered: renderer.ReactTestRenderer;
  let root: renderer.ReactTestInstance

    beforeAll(() => {
        rendered = renderer.create(component);
        root = rendered.root
    });
```

I didn't find a direct option in react-native-testing-library but leveraged its depependency react-test-renderer for it